# HTML attributes, why is it sometimes proper to prepend with 'data-'

Tags: html

I was watching an AngularJS tutorial video and the guy said that he felt much better using attributes with `data-` prepended. For instance, have `data-ng-app=""` versus just `ng-app=""`. Why is this? Did I miss some sort of rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML attributes are standardized by [World Wide Web Consortium](http://www.w3.org/) (W3C).

If you use your own attributes, the document will become invalid.

However, HTML5 introduces [`data-*` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes),

> A custom data attribute is an attribute in no namespace whose name
>   starts with the string "`data-`", has at least one character after the
>   hyphen, is [XML-compatible](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#xml-compatible), and contains no [uppercase ASCII letters](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#uppercase-ascii-letters).
>
> [Custom data attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#custom-data-attribute) are intended to store custom data private to
>   the page or application, for which there are no more appropriate
>   attributes or elements.

Comment: I never knew that they *had* to be lower-cased (I knew that JavaScript, or at least jQuery, always lower-cased any `data-*` attributes, but I hadn't realised it was because of validity/specifications).

Answer (score 1):

- You're guaranteed not to conflict with attributes that may be created in the HTML specification in the future.
- As mentioned by [Oriol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26518073/227299), an attribute like `ng-app` will make your HTML invalid.

Comment: And `data-` prefixed attributes are *valid* in HTML 5 whereas user-defined custom attributes are invalid in HTML 4.x (albeit functional).